# select option menu and capcha

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

hi am working with my website. in option menu i want to select the multiple num of thing in drop down can any one tell the js validation and also capcha.this script i can select the only one can any one modify this for selecting num of options

```
if(document.getElementById("jumpMenu").value=="0"){
    alert("Please Select the category ");
    document.getElementById("jumpMenu").value="0";
    document.getElementById("jumpMenu").focus();
    return false;
}
```

capcha validation also i want this

Answer (score 0):

in your form

```
function submit(){
    //you can add validate script here
    if(valid){
    //submit the form
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

<form>
    .....
    .....
    <button value="submit" onclick="javascript: submit()"/>
</form>
```

you can get validate script

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation. its easy to use jquery validate.

And as to validating captcha with javascript. You cannot because captcha's values are stored in server and you can validate captcha only with ajax.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ might help you in ajax. it's simple and easy. hope it helps you